# What is capture and normal phase in event handeling in Scene2D ?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I read the wiki but it's very confusing for me. Can someone explain it in easy language? There are few doubts I have 
1. Is capture listener and normal listener are also one of the many listeners provided by scene2D like InputListener, ClickListener etc

2. What is the difference between target and listener actor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, these terms describe whether you've assigned one of the types of listeners as a capture listener or not. Capture listeners allow an actor a chance to reject an event on one of its descendents. For example, some kind of group widget can decide whether to reject presses on a button that is in it based on some criteria. I think the built-in ScrollPane class uses this to prevent buttons and sliders from being manipulated while the view is being scrolled. Most people will not have a reason to use this, as it is for custom widgets that have very particular behavior.
2. Target and listener actors are usually the same. The listener actor is the actor you attached the listener to, and by default it will also be the target. But you can change the target actor to something else. This is just a feature to allow you to create listeners with custom behavior. Most people will not have a use for this. I don't even think it is used by any of the built-in classes.

The complexities of the listener system were designed to get button and widgets to react to input like a traditional UI. Unless you are designing widgets with customized input behavior, you only need

1. ChangeListener for the UI widgets (buttons and sliders).
2. If you're using Scene2D for stuff other than UI (the game scene) you'll subclass InputListener to react to touches. Or maybe GestureListener.

I built a small game using Scene2D and found that it is a bit clumsy for non-UI stuff. I wouldn't do it again, personally. So I would say 99% of people making simple games should only ever use ChangeListener.

The action system is nice for tweening stuff, but you can just add actions to the stage root and react to them externally with your own non-actor classes.